# how can I know if submit post method was success in html

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a form in html with a post method
I need to know when the response to the post request
how can I catch it?

```
<form action='MyUrl' method="post" onsubmit="sub()">
     <input type="text" name="fname" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('first name is required')"
                oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
     <button type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. When someone submits a form it becomes a completely new http request (to whatever url the `<form>`s `action=""` points). So whatever response you'd like to display, would just be part of that page.

Comment: you can use the `sub()` function to handle post submission

Comment: you can use web browser network console to view.

Comment: If you want to handle the submission within the context of the current page, then that is refered to as AJAX. You'd use javascript to make a separate http request behind the scenes, and feed the response to that request into a javascript closure. If this is what you were interested in, just read up on ajax online, it would be too generic a question to answer here.

Comment: @AselaPriyadarshana can you show my what do I need to righin in the sub() func
i need to know if the post Was successful or failed 
thanks

Comment: Try this example : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit

Comment: how do you determine if the POST request is successful or not? What processes this POST request - a php script or similar?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius  the action is a url to ather webside Ijast whant to know the respons the return from the webside

Comment: @AselaPriyadarshana  this link explane what function to run when submit but I need to know if the post succeed

Comment: @שירהחלילי then you need to communicate with the server to find out if your POST requests are successful or not, Can you add more details on your expected back-end server?